# Reading Beaglebone Black ADC through /dev/mem

Tags: embedded-linux, mmap, beagleboneblack, adc

I'm trying to write a C program for reading the ADC on the Beaglebone Black. I know I can use the sysfs way...but I'd like to see if it is possible to get the same result mapping the physical address space with /dev/mem.

I have a header file, am335x.h with the following contents:

```
#ifndef _AM335X_H_
#define _AM335X_H_

#define MMAP_OFFSET (0x44C00000)
#define MMAP_SIZE   (0x481AEFFF-MMAP_OFFSET)

/* Clock Module Memory Registers */
#define CM_WKUP (0x44E00400)
#define CM_WKUP_ADC_TSC_CLKCTRL (CM_WKUP+0xBC)
#define CM_WKUP_MODULEMODE_ENABLE (0x02)
#define CM_WKUP_IDLEST_DISABLED (0x03<<16)

#define CM_PER (0x44E00000)
#define CM_PER_EPWMSS1_CLKCTRL (CM_PER+0xCC)
#define CM_PER_EPWMSS0_CLKCTRL (CM_PER+0xD4)
#define CM_PER_EPWMSS2_CLKCTRL (CM_PER+0xD8)


/* GPIO Memory Registers */
#define GPIO_REGISTER_SIZE (4)

#define GPIO0   (0x44E07000)
#define GPIO1       (0x4804C000)
#define GPIO2       (0x481AC000)
#define GPIO3       (0x481AE000)

#define GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT (0x190)
#define GPIO_SETDATAOUT   (0x194)
#define GPIO_OE               (0x134)
#define GPIO_DATAOUT      (0x13C)
#define GPIO_DATAIN       (0x138)

/* Analog Digital Converter Memory Registers */
#define ADC_TSC (0x44E0D000)

#define ADC_CTRL (ADC_TSC+0x40)
#define ADC_STEPCONFIG_WRITE_PROTECT_OFF (0x01<<2)
#define ADC_STEPENABLE (ADC_TSC+0x54)

#define ADCSTEPCONFIG1 (ADC_TSC+0x64)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY1  (ADC_TSC+0x68)
#define ADCSTEPCONFIG2 (ADC_TSC+0x6C)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY2  (ADC_TSC+0x70)
#define ADCSTEPCONFIG3 (ADC_TSC+0x74)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY3  (ADC_TSC+0x78)
#define ADCSTEPCONFIG4 (ADC_TSC+0x7C)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY4  (ADC_TSC+0x80)
#define ADCSTEPCONFIG5 (ADC_TSC+0x84)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY5  (ADC_TSC+0x88)
#define ADCSTEPCONFIG6 (ADC_TSC+0x8C)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY6  (ADC_TSC+0x90)
#define ADCSTEPCONFIG7 (ADC_TSC+0x94)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY7  (ADC_TSC+0x98)
#define ADCSTEPCONFIG8 (ADC_TSC+0x9C)
#define ADCSTEPDELAY8  (ADC_TSC+0xA0)

#define ADC_AVG0  (0x000)
#define ADC_AVG2  (0x001)
#define ADC_AVG4  (0x010)
#define ADC_AVG8  (0x011)
#define ADC_AVG16 (0x100) 

#define ADC_FIFO0DATA (ADC_TSC+0x100)
#define ADC_FIFO_MASK (0xFFF)

typedef struct s_PWM {
  char muxmode; /*!< mux mode, 0-7, see am335x technical manual */
  char *name;   /*!< name of pwm pin, i.e.: "EHRPWM2B" */
  char *path;   /*!< path to the pwm, i.e.: "ehrpwm.2:1" */
} PWM;

typedef struct s_PIN {
  char *name;   /*!< readable name of pin, i.e.: "GPIO1_21", see beaglebone user guide */
  unsigned int gpio_bank; /*!< which of the four gpio banks is this pin in, i.e.: GPIO1, r 0x4804C000 */
  uint8_t gpio; /*!< pin number on the am335x processor */
  uint8_t bank_id; /*!< pin number within each bank, should be 0-31 */
  char *mux;    /*!< file name for setting mux */
  uint8_t eeprom; /*!< position in eeprom */
  unsigned char pwm_present; /*!< whether or not this pin can be used for PWM */
  PWM pwm;      /*!< pwm struct if pwm_present is true */

} PIN;

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define USR0  ((PIN){     "GPIO1_21",      GPIO1,     0,   21,   "",                0,     FALSE, 0   })
#define USR1  ((PIN){     "GPIO1_22",      GPIO1,     0,   22,   "",                0,     FALSE, 0   })
#define USR2  ((PIN){     "GPIO1_23",      GPIO1,     0,   23,   "",                0,     FALSE, 0   })
#define USR3  ((PIN){     "GPIO1_24",      GPIO1,     0,   24,   "",                0,     FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_3  ((PIN){   "GPIO1_6",     GPIO1,     38,   6,   "gpmc_ad6",        26,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_4  ((PIN){   "GPIO1_7",     GPIO1,     39,   7,   "gpmc_ad7",        27,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_5  ((PIN){   "GPIO1_2",     GPIO1,     34,   2,   "gpmc_ad2",        22,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_6  ((PIN){   "GPIO1_3",     GPIO1,     35,   3,   "gpmc_ad3",        23,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_7  ((PIN){   "TIMER4",      GPIO2,     66,   2,   "gpmc_advn_ale",   41,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_8  ((PIN){   "TIMER7",      GPIO2,     67,   3,   "gpmc_oen_ren",    44,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_9  ((PIN){   "TIMER5",      GPIO2,     69,   5,   "gpmc_ben0_cle",   42,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_10 ((PIN){   "TIMER6",      GPIO2,     68,   4,   "gpmc_wen",        43,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_11 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_13",    GPIO1,     45,   13,  "gpmc_ad13",       29,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_12 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_12",    GPIO1,     44,   12,  "gpmc_ad12",       28,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_13 ((PIN){   "EHRPWM2B",    GPIO0,     23,   23,  "gpmc_ad9",        15,    TRUE,  (PWM){4, "EHRPWM2B", "ehrpwm.2:1"}})
#define P8_14 ((PIN){   "GPIO0_26",    GPIO0,     26,   26,  "gpmc_ad10",       16,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_15 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_15",    GPIO1,     47,   15,  "gpmc_ad15",       31,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_16 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_14",    GPIO1,     46,   14,  "gpmc_ad14",       30,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_17 ((PIN){   "GPIO0_27",    GPIO0,     27,   27,  "gpmc_ad11",       17,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_18 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_1",     GPIO2,     65,   1,   "gpmc_clk",        40,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_19 ((PIN){   "EHRPWM2A",    GPIO0,     22,   22,  "gpmc_ad8",        14,    TRUE,  (PWM){4, "EHRPWM2A", "ehrpwm.2:0"}})
#define P8_20 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_31",    GPIO1,     63,   31,  "gpmc_csn2",       39,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_21 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_30",    GPIO1,     62,   30,  "gpmc_csn1",       38,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_22 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_5",     GPIO1,     37,   5,   "gpmc_ad5",        25,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_23 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_4",     GPIO1,     36,   4,   "gpmc_ad4",        24,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_24 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_1",     GPIO1,     33,   1,   "gpmc_ad1",        21,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_25 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_0",     GPIO1,     32,   0,   "gpmc_ad0",        20,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_26 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_29",    GPIO1,     61,   29,  "gpmc_csn0",       37,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_27 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_22",    GPIO2,     86,   22,  "lcd_vsync",       57,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_28 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_24",    GPIO2,     88,   24,  "lcd_pclk",        59,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_29 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_23",    GPIO2,     87,   23,  "lcd_hsync",       58,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_30 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_25",    GPIO2,     89,   25,  "lcd_ac_bias_en",  60,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_31 ((PIN){   "UART5_CTSN",  GPIO0,     10,   10,  "lcd_data14",       7,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_32 ((PIN){   "UART5_RTSN",  GPIO0,     11,   11,  "lcd_data15",       8,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_33 ((PIN){   "UART4_RTSN",  GPIO0,     9,    9,   "lcd_data13",       6,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_34 ((PIN){   "UART3_RTSN",  GPIO2,     81,   17,  "lcd_data11",      56,    TRUE,  (PWM){2, "EHRPWM1B", "ehrpwm.1:1"}})
#define P8_35 ((PIN){   "UART4_CTSN",  GPIO0,     8,    8,   "lcd_data12",       5,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_36 ((PIN){   "UART3_CTSN",  GPIO2,     80,   16,  "lcd_data10",      55,    TRUE,  (PWM){2, "EHRPWM1A", "ehrpwm.1:0"}})
#define P8_37 ((PIN){   "UART5_TXD",   GPIO2,     78,   14,  "lcd_data8",       53,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_38 ((PIN){   "UART5_RXD",   GPIO2,     79,   15,  "lcd_data9",       54,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_39 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_12",    GPIO2,     76,   12,  "lcd_data6",       51,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_40 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_13",    GPIO2,     77,   13,  "lcd_data7",       52,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_41 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_10",    GPIO2,     74,   10,  "lcd_data4",       49,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_42 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_11",    GPIO2,     75,   11,  "lcd_data5",       50,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_43 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_8",     GPIO2,     72,   8,   "lcd_data2",       47,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_44 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_9",     GPIO2,     73,   9,   "lcd_data3",       48,    FALSE, 0   })
#define P8_45 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_6",     GPIO2,     70,   6,   "lcd_data0",       45,    TRUE,  (PWM){3, "EHRPWM2A", "ehrpwm.2:0"}})
#define P8_46 ((PIN){   "GPIO2_7",     GPIO2,     71,   7,   "lcd_data1",       46,    TRUE,  (PWM){3, "EHRPWM2B", "ehrpwm.2:1"}})

#define P9_11 ((PIN){   "UART4_RXD",   GPIO0,     30,  30,   "gpmc_wait0",       18,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_12 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_28",    GPIO1,     60,  28,   "gpmc_ben1",        36,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_13 ((PIN){   "UART4_TXD",   GPIO0,     31,  31,   "gpmc_wpn",         19,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_14 ((PIN){   "EHRPWM1A",    GPIO1,     50,  18,   "gpmc_a2",          34,   TRUE, (PWM){6, "EHRPWM1A", "ehrpwm.1:0"}})
#define P9_15 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_16",    GPIO1,     48,  16,   "mii1_rxd3",        32,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_16 ((PIN){   "EHRPWM1B",    GPIO1,     51,  19,   "gpmc_a3",          35,   TRUE, (PWM){6, "EHRPWM1B", "ehrpwm.1:1"}})
#define P9_17 ((PIN){   "I2C1_SCL",    GPIO0,      5,   5,   "spi0_cs0",          3,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_18 ((PIN){   "I2C1_SDA",    GPIO0,      4,   4,   "spi0_d1",           2,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_19 ((PIN){   "I2C2_SCL",    GPIO0,     13,  13,   "uart1_rtsn",        9,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_20 ((PIN){   "I2C2_SDA",    GPIO0,     12,  12,   "uart1_ctsn",       10,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_21 ((PIN){   "UART2_TXD",   GPIO0,      3,   3,   "spi0_d0",           1,   TRUE, (PWM){3, "EHRPWM0B", "ehrpwm.0:1"}})
#define P9_22 ((PIN){   "UART2_RXD",   GPIO0,      2,   2,   "spi0_sclk",         0,   TRUE, (PWM){3, "EHRPWM0A", "ehrpwm.0:0"}})
#define P9_23 ((PIN){   "GPIO1_17",    GPIO1,     49,  17,   "gpmc_a1",          33,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_24 ((PIN){   "UART1_TXD",   GPIO0,     15,  15,   "uart1_txd",        12,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_25 ((PIN){   "GPIO3_21",    GPIO3,    117,  21,   "mcasp0_ahclkx",    66,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_26 ((PIN){   "UART1_RXD",   GPIO0,     14,  14,   "uart1_rxd",        11,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_27 ((PIN){   "GPIO3_19",    GPIO3,    115,  19,   "mcasp0_fsr",       64,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_28 ((PIN){   "SPI1_CS0",    GPIO3,    113,  17,   "mcasp0_ahclkr",    63,   TRUE, (PWM){4, "ECAPPWM2", "ecap.2"}})
#define P9_29 ((PIN){   "SPI1_D0",     GPIO3,    111,  15,   "mcasp0_fsx",       61,   TRUE, (PWM){1, "EHRPWM0B", "ehrpwm.0:1"}})
#define P9_30 ((PIN){   "SPI1_D1",     GPIO3,    112,  16,   "mcasp0_axr0",      62,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_31 ((PIN){   "SPI1_SCLK",   GPIO3,    110,  14,   "mcasp0_aclkx",     65,   TRUE, (PWM){1, "EHRPWM0A", "ehrpwm.0:0"}})
#define P9_33 ((PIN){   "AIN4",        0,          4,   4,   "",                 71,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_35 ((PIN){   "AIN6",        0,          6,   6,   "",                 73,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_36 ((PIN){   "AIN5",        0,          5,   5,   "",                 72,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_37 ((PIN){   "AIN2",        0,          2,   2,   "",                 69,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_38 ((PIN){   "AIN3",        0,          3,   3,   "",                 70,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_39 ((PIN){   "AIN0",        0,          0,   0,   "",                 67,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_40 ((PIN){   "AIN1",        0,          1,   1,   "",                 68,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_41 ((PIN){   "CLKOUT2",     GPIO0,     20,  20,   "xdma_event_intr1", 13,   FALSE, 0})
#define P9_42 ((PIN){   "GPIO0_7",     GPIO0,      7,   7,   "ecap0_in_pwm0_out", 4,   TRUE, (PWM){0, "ECAPPWM0", "ecap.0"}})


#define INPUT    ((unsigned char)(1))
#define OUTPUT   ((unsigned char)(0))
#define PULLUP   ((unsigned char)(1))
#define PULLDOWN ((unsigned char)(0))
#define DISABLED ((unsigned char)(2))

#define CONFIG_MUX_PATH "/sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux"



#endif
```

And then I have my C program, ADC_mapping.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
//#include <inttypes.h>
#include "am335x.h"


static volatile uint32_t *map;
static char mapped = FALSE;

// Function declaration

int init();
int adc_init();
int analogRead(PIN p);

// Main function
int main()
{
        
        uint32_t adc0;
        int count = 0;

        while(count <= 1000)
        {
                adc0 = analogRead(P9_39);  
                printf("Value AIN0: %zu \n", adc0); 
                usleep (50000);                  
        }


        return  0;
}

/**
 * map /dev/mem to memory
 *
 * @returns whether or not the mapping of /dev/mem into memory was successful
 */
int init() {
        if(!mapped) {
                int fd;
                fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
                if(fd == -1) {
                        perror("Unable to open /dev/mem");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                map = (uint32_t*)mmap(NULL, MMAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, MMAP_OFFSET);
                if(map == MAP_FAILED) {
                        close(fd);
                        perror("Unable to map /dev/mem");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                mapped = TRUE;
        }
        return mapped;
}

/**
 * Initializee the Analog-Digital Converter
 */
int adc_init() {
        init();

        // enable the CM_WKUP_ADC_TSC_CLKCTRL with CM_WKUP_MODUELEMODE_ENABLE
        map[(CM_WKUP_ADC_TSC_CLKCTRL-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] |= CM_WKUP_MODULEMODE_ENABLE;

        // wait for the enable to complete
        while(!(map[(CM_WKUP_ADC_TSC_CLKCTRL-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] & CM_WKUP_MODULEMODE_ENABLE)) {
                // waiting for adc clock module to initialize
                //printf("Waiting for CM_WKUP_ADC_TSC_CLKCTRL to enable with MODULEMODE_ENABLE\n");
        }
        // software reset, set bit 1 of sysconfig high?
        // make sure STEPCONFIG write protect is off
        map[(ADC_CTRL-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] |= ADC_STEPCONFIG_WRITE_PROTECT_OFF;

        // set up each ADCSTEPCONFIG for each ain pin
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG1-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x00<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY1-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG2-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x01<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY2-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG3-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x02<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY3-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG4-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x03<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY4-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG5-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x04<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY5-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG6-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x05<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY6-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG7-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x06<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY7-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;
        map[(ADCSTEPCONFIG8-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] = 0x07<<19 | ADC_AVG16;
        map[(ADCSTEPDELAY8-MMAP_OFFSET)/4]  = (0x0F)<<24;

        // enable the ADC
        map[(ADC_CTRL-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] |= 0x01;
}

/**
 * Read in from an analog pin
 *
 * @param p pin to read value from
 * @returns the analog value of pin p
 */
int analogRead(PIN p) {
        init();
        
        // the clock module is not enabled
        if(map[(CM_WKUP_ADC_TSC_CLKCTRL-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] & CM_WKUP_IDLEST_DISABLED)
                adc_init();
        
        // enable the step sequencer for this pin
        map[(ADC_STEPENABLE-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] |= (0x01<<(p.bank_id+1));

        // return the the FIFO0 data register
        return map[(ADC_FIFO0DATA-MMAP_OFFSET)/4] & ADC_FIFO_MASK;
}
```

The output is:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyHrk.png)

But the value that should be reading is:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyn9t.png)

Any idea about the reason?

Comment: How is your kernel configured?  If there is already a driver built & installed for the ADC, then your program is interfering with the driver's control of that device.

Comment: Shouldn't `MMAP_SIZE` be defined as `#define MMAP_SIZE   (0x481AF000-MMAP_OFFSET)` (i.e. one more byte than the present value)?

Comment: @sawdust I searched for it using "lsmod", just in case, but there is not any driver built and installed for the ADC...

Comment: @IanAbbott Tried modifying that define, but the output doesn't change.

Comment: *"I searched for it using "lsmod",..."* -- Searched for what?  A driver that is statically linked into the kernel image would not exist as a *loadable* module.   Besides the kernel build configuration (i.e. the **.config** file), there's the Device Tree, the interrupts in use (**/proc/interrupts**), and the memory regions in use by drivers (**/proc/iomem**) to examine.

Comment: @sawdust You were rigth... The problem was there. I can't access to the ADC that way due to the Image that I'm using. Thanks!